# PHPfox CDN (Content Delivery Network) Specific key use

Tags: cdn, phpfox

I have already added CDN to my phpfox social network.
My first server is almost full.
Now I have add another another cdn. It is also working fine.
But The problem is, the contents are being delivered/saved one time in first cdn server, Again to second cdn server.

Now I want to save contents in second cdn server.
If I remove key of first cdn then The contents are missing all image,video, and other files of first server.

I want to run two cdn servers but The contents will be saved only second cdn's .

Following are codes: Please edit it.

/home/horjecom/public_html/include/setting/cdn.sett.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * [PHPFOX_HEADER]
 * 
 * @copyright  [PHPFOX_COPYRIGHT]
 * @author   natio
 * @package   PhpFox
 * @version   $Id: cdn.sett.php.new 3956 2012-03-01 12:28:26Z Raymond_Benc $
 */

defined('PHPFOX') or exit('NO DICE!');

$aServers = array(    
    array(
        'upload' => 'http://1.mydomain.com/', 
        'file' => 'http://1.mydomain.com/file/', 
        'key' => '123'
    ),



    array(
        'upload' => 'http://2.mydomain.com/', 
        'file' => 'http://2.mydomain.com/file/', 
        'key' => '1234'
    )
); 


?>
```

Please edit it, Whereby I can use multi keys cdn and contents will be saved to last added cdn server (key)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using phpFox cdn. phpFox cdn allows you add many servers. But when users are adding the new content, you can't control which server will be stored. It gets random a server. There is no solution if the server is full (with default code).

You should remove your real keys here, if someone know your keys, they can get/add/delete your files on your servers. Key is for verify, each cdn server, you can use a different key.

Comment: I think it is possible to solve my problem if the matter will be looked by a major php developer.